# Correct way to set up a dev / qa/ prod organizations in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Consider the following scenario:
CRM is being used as an application development platform where in multiple applications (CRM solutions) are being built across many development ORGs and these solutions
will be ultimately hosted under one organization in a PROD org.
The dev environment looks as follows:

1) An unmnanaged "Common" solution containing common entities,roles and other artifacts in an org 
   called COMMON

2) Team A working on unmanaged Solution  1 in ORG 1 in which COMMON has been imported as a managed 
   solution

3) Team B working on unmanaged Solution  2 in ORG 2 in which COMMON has been imported as a managed
   solution

4) Team C working on unmanaged  Solution 3 in ORG 3 in which COMMON has been imported as a managed 
   solution

There is another called INTEGRATION which is intended for all applications(Solutions) to come to together as managed solutions

Questions:

1) Is it a good idea to have multiple applications developed in parallel in the same development 
   org? 
   For example would it make sense to have Team A & Team B share Org 1 while they are doing 
   development on Solutions A & Solutions B respectively?

2) If any of the applications above need site map customizations should these customizations be made 
   and included in the respective managed solutions before they
   are imported into INTEGRATION or should all site map customizatons be made in INTEGRATION and 
   these customization in turn be exported out as a managed solution(containing just the sitemap) 
   for importing into the PRODUCTION org eventually.

3) Solutions 1-3 have custom entities in their respective orgs and need to add privileges to these 
   entities (Read, Write etc.) for a role say "Role X" that is coming from the managed common
   solution that is installed in their respective orgs. Should privileges to roles on entities be 
   granted and included as part of the respective managed solutions or should this provisioning also 
   be done in the INTEGRATION org?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to consider splitting up this question into.multiple questions.  One question for each of your questions listed. That way people can answer each question vigilant individually and not have to answer all 3 at once.

Answer (score 1):

1) You're fine to have multiple solutions being developed in the same org simultaneously.  We do this often and really the only issues arise when we're dealing with the same entity.  In a perfect world, your COMMON (which is your core library) would be a managed solution in this solution development org.  In fact, I would highly recommend keeping the COMMON isolated as much as possible, documented highly, and automated to keep in an SVN.

2) Sitemap is generally easy to do any which way you want.  The ribbon is the killer.  Anyhow, I like to make the changes manually in UAT and then import those to PROD.  This isn't the ideal way, just the way that seems to cause the least amount of mistakes.  Importing from DEV seems to overwrite existing items since it's all about "Last in wins".

3) I would keep these in the solution since they are dependant on the application.  Now if the DEVs aren't the kind of people to manage this because of red tape or a user disconnect, I would build an unmanaged integration solution inside of UAT that is tied to each solution.  So solution-A-integration, solution-B-integration, etc. to be handled by someone else.  These would then be exported out of UAT to be imported as managed solutions into PROD.